# Extracting text from Outlook email to Excel - check formatting

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook, strikethrough

I am extracting text from emails to Excel, but I have problem with text which has special font, Strikethrough. After extracting it looses its format and it looks like all other text, but strikethroughing changes the meaning. In that case I need to use condition, something like this:

```
If lines(j).Font.Strikethrough = True Then lines(j) = "Deleted " & lines(j)
```

Does anybody have an experience with that?

Main part of the CODE:

```
Sub Export_Outlook_Emails_To_Excel()

Dim Folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim BodyMail As String
Dim lines As Variant
Dim row As Integer
Dim DATA As Worksheet
Dim j, Items As Long

Set DATA = Worksheets("DATA")

'check emails – I deleted not important rows so normally it gioes through all 
emails in directory
Set folder = Outlook.Session.Folders(„Archive“).Folders("Inbox").Folders("Changes")
Items = Folder.Items.Count
BodyMail = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).Body
lines = Split(BodyMail, Chr(9)) ' split multi lines in a cell by TAB 
' EXTRACT DATA FROM EMAIL 
For j = LBound(lines) To UBound(lines) 'export DATA from email into temporary 
DATA sheet        

' --- HERE I NEED INSERT THE CONDITION, SOMETHING LIKE THIS ---
If lines(j).Font.Strikethrough = True Then lines(j) = "Striketrough font : " & lines(j)

DATA.Cells(row, 1) = (lines(j))
Next j

End Sub
```

Comment: Does the code run? Can you add an example image of the email body

Comment: The problem is your array only stores the text, no formatting (lines = Split), you'll need to search for a way to copy the whole body

Answer (score 1):

You would need to work with the `HTMLBody` property instead of the plain text `Body` and parse the returned HTML.